# jQuery IE animation on text gives strange effect

Tags: jquery, opacity

Someone knows solution for this kind of IE bug?

http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/3007/strangeopacity.png

Using 1.4.4 jQuery

font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14pt;

IE7 & IE8 same effect

```
function loop_fade(){
    $('#m_notices_c').animate({opacity:0.1},500,function(){
        $('#m_notices_c').animate({opacity:1},500,loop_fade);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    loop_fade();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Cleartype glitch and the problem is documented nicely at http://blog.bmn.name/2008/03/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/

Comment: Thanks mate i'll look into it a bit later and accept your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with ie handling transparent backgrounds with alpha blending.

the easiest solution should be something like

```
#m_notices_c { background:#fff; }
```